# Mute/Unmute Mic volume from Unity

Tags: unity

*(I've gone through tons of articles on this, but not found a working solution I can run in Unity 5.5.2+)*

I'm looking for C# code I can run that will allow me to mute and unmute the default microphone.  This ONLY needs to run on Windows 10.

Comment: By mute/unmute, do you mean stopping and restarting recording using the Microphone Start/End methods? Or zeroing & restoring the playback volume of an AudioSource that's playing the microphone input, while it continues recording? Or are you trying to toggle the state of the device itself?

Comment: the device itself.

Comment: I.e. I'm setting up a theme park game, and the user will wear a headset.  The mic will be setup to play through a set of speakers in a separate room.  But only at certain times.  I want the game to be able to mute or otherwise de-activate the players mic.  (not for a recording)